# How export jar not executable with their lib

Tags: java, jar, api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm working on a project that will add mediator in the header of the backend request of api manager so I need to export jar(not runnable) that need libraries, could you please tell me how to resolve the exceptions of class not found
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are going to add external libraries, you have to add them in to $WSO2_Product_home/repository/components/lib folder.

Then those libraries will be added to dropins folder ($Product_home/repository/components/dropins) while server starts.

Note: If you add libraries while server running, you should restart the server.